# nginx configuration for an app with backend petitions against a frontend with SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, get

I have read several SOF posts but I have not been able to get the solutions to work in my specific case.

I have deployed an APP which has a API in nodejs/express and front-end in angular.

The end point for the backend is xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3900/api

I've made an Angular build and take it to nginx which has SSL installed.

When I go to my domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), front-end works well, but, when I try to login, this front-end makes a http request to https://www.example.com/api which receives a console error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This is my .conf for nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        index index index.html index.htm;
        root /var/www/html;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo/privkey.pem;

        #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3900/;                
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
        

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off; access_log off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
                log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
        }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved my question, in case it helps someone, my .conf looks like:

```
location /api {
                proxy_pass http://www.example.com:3900;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                
        }
```

And, then, petitions from the front-end to the api, are made pointing to https://www.example.com/api/foo